# Encountering error when trying to run `forge create`

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge

I am in the process of switching to foundry for contract development and testing. I have written some basic contracts, and am trying to use the alchemy RPC URL to deploy the contracts onto the testnet via MetaMask.

I have written tests which pass successfully, but when I try to run `forge create ...` I get this error:

```
Error:
(code: 3, message: execution reverted, data: Some(String("0x161b906f00000000000000000000000039463d1d009c32806a162df5d7e152d6b4709fda")))
```

...I haven't managed to find any recurrance of this error on forums etc, so was hoping for some help here.

Here's the **create** command I am running:

`forge create --rpc-url https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/demo --private-key 0x1621e5a0ba99c1a1b10e31240c54241c60ce39f017f9d7fcd94c89012byb36b7  src/MyContractFactory.sol:MyContractFactory`

Comment: Where are you running it from? Are you CD'd into the dir of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include your Alchemy's API key into your RPC url, like stated in [Alchemy's docs](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/goerli-vs-sepolia):
`https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/[YOUR-API-KEY]`

However they do state that [Goerli will be deprecated by January 2024](https://www.alchemy.com/blog/goerli-faucet-deprecation), and they recommend using the [Sepolia testnet](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/sepolia-testnet) instead.

Two other things I would consider in your command:

1. Make sure you're CD'd into the directory you're working in.
2. Write the name of the contract you're trying to write at the beginning of the statement, like so: `forge create MyContractFactory`.

Lastly, I really do hope the private key you just posted here is a dummy with no real funds, and in any case - I would store it in an `.env` file and use an argument instead. 
*(also relevant to API keys)*

---

A suggested `.env` file would look like this, using the Sepolia testnet:

```
SEPOLIA_RPC_URL=https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/[YOUR-API-KEY]
PRIVATE_KEY=0x1621e5a0ba99c1a1b10e31240c54241c60ce39f017f9d7fcd94c89012aca36b7
```

*Don't forget to `source .env` in the terminal after saving the file.*

Then, your create command would look like this:

```
forge create MyContractFactory --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY
```

Comment: Concise and clean, thank you. The key is autogen from anvil - but I will edit it anyway, to stop the devils among us.